# EC2 Instance Connect - IAM policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Syntax errors in policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I'm running into the 'MalformedPolicyDocument' error while creating my IAM policy. This is for configuring ec2 instance connect.

```
{
    "Version": "2022-6-26",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789:instance/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:osuser": "ktian"
            }
        }
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
}
```

Here's the create policy command I used:

```
aws iam create-policy --policy-name IAM-policy --policy-document file://iam-policy.json
```

As far as I can see the actual syntax in the policy file is ok, is there some another issue in the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

Version `2022-6-26` is **incorrect**. The [latest version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html) available is `2012-10-17`.